# PHP MSSQL DateDiff Between Date Completed in next result

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, datediff

I have a SQL table that has rows of populated data from: punched in times, tasks completed during the day, followed by punched out time. I need come up with a PHP MSSQL query to get the elapsed time between each row. Preferably using `DATEDIFF(second, [Date Completed], [Date Completed]) / 3600.0 AS DiffDate`.

How do I get it to retain the `Date Completed` from the first result so that I can use it in the next result, to obtain the elapsed time between the two dates?

My query looks like the following:

```
SELECT PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[id],
    users.alias,
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Order Number],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Job Name],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Door Number],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Qty Display],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Door Counter],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Jamb Counter],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Work Center],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Completed By],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Date Completed],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Hours Earned],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Elapsed Time],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Applied Time],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[ID]

FROM users INNER JOIN PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail
    ON users.[Employee Number] = PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Completed By] 

WHERE [Completed By]='081'
    AND ([Date Completed] >= '10/21/2015 00:00:00'
    AND [Date Completed] <= '10/21/2015 23:59:59') 

GROUP BY
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[id], users.alias,
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Order Number],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Job Name],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Door Number],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Qty Display],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Door Counter],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Jamb Counter],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Work Center],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Completed By],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Date Completed],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Hours Earned],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Elapsed Time],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[Applied Time],
    PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail.[ID]

ORDER BY [Completed By], [Date Completed]
```

The results looks like the following ...

```
Work Station  | Date Completed           | Elapsed Time  | ID
---------------------------------------------------------------
Punched In    | 2015-10-21 05:58:00.000  |       0       | 6816

Task1         | 2015-10-21 11:27:11.000  |       0       | 6212

Task2         | 2015-10-21 11:27:33.000  |       0       | 6219

Task3         | 2015-10-21 11:28:22.000  |       0       | 6651

Punched Out   | 2015-10-21 14:42:00.000  |       0       | 7318
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit Ram but it won't allow me to approve it without 2k reputation.

Answer (score 0):

After a decent nights sleep I managed to rewrite the process to calculate the elapsed time between each task using the following query and managed to get the results needed ...

```
SELECT b.[id], a.[Completed By],
a.[Date Completed] AS newDateCompleted,
b.[Date Completed] AS oldDateCompleted,  
DATEDIFF(second, a.[Date Completed],b.[Date Completed]) / 3600.0 AS diff
FROM(
    SELECT id, [Completed By], [Date Completed],
        (
            SELECT count(*)
            FROM PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail
            WHERE [Completed By]=T.[Completed By] AND [Date Completed]<T.[Date Completed]
        )+1
    AS rank1
    FROM PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail
    AS T
    )
AS a INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT id, [Completed By], [Date Completed],
        (
            SELECT count(*)
            FROM PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail
            WHERE [Completed By]=T1.[Completed By] AND [Date Completed]<T1.[Date Completed]
        )
        AS rank2
        FROM PDT_Mill_Capacity_Labor_Detail
        AS T1
    )
AS b ON (a.rank1=b.rank2) AND (a.[Completed By] = b.[Completed By])

WHERE a.[Completed By]='084' AND (a.[Date Completed] >='11/4/2015' AND a.[Date Completed] <='11/4/2015 23:59:59')

ORDER BY a.[Completed By], a.[Date Completed] ASC
```